# How can i make a query that will find only first and last name

Tags: solr

The problem is this: I've got a column (named customername) which consist of names for Example "JOHN LENARD SMITH" and so on.

So I want to make a query which will get all the names that has first name 'JOHN' and last name 'SMITH'; The second name doesn't matter so i will put * wildcard character.

Also there is a bigger problem: I should be able in a case if the user writes "JOHN LENARD SMITH" to find this exact person

what I have tried :

1.
I made the field text_ws type and tested the following queries:
The problem is this: I've got a column (named name)which consist of names for Example "Иван Кирилов Петров", "Нина Семова Мариножа" and so on.

So I want to make a query which will get all the names that has first name 'Иван' and last name 'Петров'; The second name doesn't matter so i will put * wildcard character.

Also there is a bigger problem: I should be able in a case if the user writes "Иван Кирилов Петров" to find this exact person

what I have tried :

I made the field text_ws type and tested the following queries:

```
q=cust_name:JOHN*SMITH


q=cust_name:/JOHN.*SMITH/
```

nothing works! i"M desperate i think i will never solve this task.

Comment: PLEASE SOMEONE TO EXPLAIN WHY tommorow when I WROTE name/JOHN.*SMITH/ it works perfectly and yesterday it again worked tommorow then my colleagues just added a new column in the schema without even touching my column name and then it stopped and now it works again! I don't know maybe if there there is a chance to index in a different way every time I make a data import.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `text_ws` field, you will need to have whitespace in your queries so that Solr can split the query into terms that will match the indexed values. For your JOHN SMITH example, the following should work:

```
 q=cust_name:JOHN * SMITH
```

If you are looking for the occurrence of JOHN or SMITH anywhere in the name, you could also just use the following. But it sounds like position is important to you based on the example.

```
 q=cust_name:JOHN SMITH
```

Also, using preserving the whitespace in the query will enable the search for JOHN LENARD SMITH to work as well.

```
 q=cust_name:JOHN LENARD SMITH
```

Finally, I would recommend adding the [LowerCaseTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory) to your `text_ws` field so that terms are indexed and searched as lowercase, otherwise a search for `John * Smith` will not match because of the case difference.

Comment: No unfortunately when i Write JOHN * SMITH it gives me all the names with that start with JOHN! I think i'm going crazy with this solr! I am sure that yesterday in the morning it worked perfectly with JOHN*SMITH

Answer (score -1):

Have the user enter the name in three seperate fields.  Concatenate the results.  If there are any blanks, replace with a wildcard.

Comment: wit doesn't matter if the user enters the search name in one field or three (when it's in one field i just split the name according to the withspaces so i have the seperate names)! the thing that matters is that inteh database the three names are in one column and my query is not working

Comment: What platform are you using?  (MS Access, SQL Server 2008, etc...)